# Node.js "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have this node.js app (using socket.io) that is going to be used for monitoring changes made to network configuration changes in a production environment. It monitors a spool directory for new files then pushes the info to a web client. When I try to run it I get "ERROR: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined." Any help would be appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

// Runtime configuration
const SPOOLDIR = process.env['HOME'] + "/spool";        // Where to collect files
const INTERVAL = 5000;                          // How often to scan
const GRACE = 2000;                             // Minimum age of file before processing

// Dependency modules
const fs = require("fs");
const os = require("os");
const util = require("util");
const app = require('http').createServer(handler)
const io = require('socket.io')(app);

// Global variables:
// - File cache: stat structures by filename
var CACHE={};

// Mini C STDIO  printf/fprintf routines :)
//
const STDOUT=1;
const STDERR=2;
const fprintf = function(fd, fmt) {
    utilfmt_args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    var str = util.format.apply(null, utilfmt_args);
    fs.writeSync(fd, str);
}
const printf = function() {
    Array.prototype.unshift.call(arguments, STDOUT);
    fprintf.apply(null, arguments);
}


const startFileScan = function() {
    fs.readdir(SPOOLDIR, processFileResults);
}

const processFileResults = function(err, files) {
    fprintf(STDERR, "processFileResult: %d file(s) found in %s\n", files.length, SPOOLDIR);
    if (err!=undefined) {
        fprintf(STDERR, "Can't read spool directory %s: %s\n", SPOOLDIR, err.code);
        return;
    }

    // Expire any items from the cache that are no longer present
    for (var f in CACHE) {
        if (files.indexOf(f)==-1) {
//          fprintf(STDERR, "Removing file %s from cache\n", f);
            delete CACHE[f];
        }
    }

    // Check any files that are there for modifications, processing them if so
    var currentFile = undefined;
        const doStat = function(err, stats) {
        if (err) {
            fprintf(STDERR, "Error stat()ing %s: %s\n", currentFile, err.code);
        } else {
            if (currentFile!==undefined) {
//              fprintf(STDERR, "Checking file %s with mtime %s against cache\n", currentFile, stats.mtime);
                if (!(currentFile in CACHE) || !(CACHE[currentFile].getTime()==stats.mtime.getTime())) {
                    if (stats.mtime.getTime() + GRACE < Date.now()) {
//                      fprintf(STDERR, "  Updating cache for file %s with mtime %s\n", currentFile, stats.mtime);
                        CACHE[currentFile]=stats.mtime;
//                      fprintf(STDERR, "  File %s has been modified longer than %d ms ago: scheduling for processing\n", currentFile, GRACE);
                        process.nextTick(outputDiffReport, currentFile, CACHE[currentFile]);
                }
            }           
        }
        currentFile = files.pop();
        if (currentFile===undefined) {
//          fprintf(STDERR, "File scan completed: re-scheduling next scan\n");
            process.nextTick(function() { setTimeout(startFileScan, INTERVAL); });
        } else {
            fs.stat(SPOOLDIR + "/" + currentFile, doStat);                      
        }
    };
    process.nextTick(doStat);
}

// App library routines
//
    const outputDiffReport = function(filename, mtime) {
//  fprintf(STDERR, "Processing file %s\n", filename);
    var data="";
    try {
        data = fs.readFileSync(SPOOLDIR + "/" + filename, { encoding: "utf8" });
    } catch(err) {
        fprintf(STDERR, "Can't read incoming filename %s: %s\n", filename, err.code);
    }
    content = data.split(/\n/).filter(function(x) { return x.match(/^[+\-#\[]/); }).join("\n"); 
//  content = data.split(/\n/).filter(function(x) { return ! x.match(/^\s*$/); }).join("\n");   

    io.emit('update', { 'content':  content,
                        'mtime':    mtime.toISOString(),
                        'file':     filename
                    });

fs.unlink(SPOOLDIR + "/" + filename, function() {});
}


// HTTP bootstrap handler routine. Serves out the client HTML
function handler (req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html',
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading index.html');
    }
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
}

process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {
  console.log("ERROR: ", err.message);
  process.exit(1);
});

app.listen(8080);

process.nextTick(startFileScan);
```

Comment: Seems that no files are being passed to the processFileResults() function, so it's undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be a permissions issue with the spool directory. The user I created to run the program did not have read access to it.

Comment: Why junos-automation tag? Can you please remove the same.

Comment: Because it's looking for files sent from juniper event options. Will remove the tag though.

Answer (score 1):

When `processFileResults` is called, it will either get an error as first param, or it will succeed and give you `null` as first param and the files as the second.

Before you try to access the `files`, you should check for the error and handle it. Also, it doesn't make sense semantically to check if error is `undefined`, since it can only be `null` or an error.

```
const processFileResults = function(err, files) {
    if (err) {
        fprintf(STDERR, "Can't read spool directory %s: %s\n", SPOOLDIR, err.code);
        return;
    }
    fprintf(STDERR, "processFileResult: %d file(s) found in %s\n", files.length, SPOOLDIR);
}
```

Comment: @WillyB Also to add to this, have you considered using a package such as `chokidar`? https://www.npmjs.com/package/chokidar.  Based on the description of what you're doing, it seems you just need a file watcher to tell you when a file change/add occurs.  If that's ultimately what you're doing, using that it will make your code so much less confusing, as well as a lot more efficient.

Comment: Havent hearken of chokidar but I will look into it if it makes things simpler.